# one row is discarded while importing shapefile into postgres

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

Please help me in following issue. I need to import a polyline shapefile into Postgres9.1 through shp2pgsql command.When i did like this, i got an error as

**"NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "new2_gid_seq" for serial column "new2.gid"
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "new2_pkey" for table "new2"
Query result with 1 row discarded.
Query returned successfully with no result in 1063 ms.**

because of this error, i couldn't able to do further processes.Please madam do needful thing![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that "1 row discarded" is not an error.  It is just a message indicating that one of the SQL statements returned a record that was discarded in the transaction.

If you were to run something very simple like the following in pgAdmin...

```
BEGIN;
SELECT 1;
SELECT 2;
COMMIT;
```

The messages returned would be...

```
Query result with 1 row discarded.

Query result with 1 row discarded.
```